# Touch Events Windows Phone 7.8

Tags: jquery, windows-phone

I´m developing a web application with jquery ui and a helper plugin for mapping the touch events to mouse events.

Now I found out that a Windows 8 Touch Device, with an IE10 installed needs some CSS Hack `-ms-touch-action: none;`

1. What version of IE runs on Windows phone 7.8. IE9?
2. Does IE9 support touch events?
3. Is there any documentation about touch events in IE9?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7.8 is know to use Internet Explorer 9.

Unfortunately it does [not support Touch Events](http://caniuse.com/#search=touch).

If you really need to support Internet Explorer 9 with touch I recommend you take a look at [HandJS](http://handjs.codeplex.com/). It is *"a polyfill for supporting pointer events on every browser"*.

> Works on IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari Support for: pointerdown,
>   pointermove, pointerup, pointercancel, pointerenter, pointerleave,
>   pointerout, pointerover
>
> Fallback to mouse
>
> CSS analysis to support touch-action:none (can be
>   disabled with  HANDJS.doNotProcessCSS = true; )
>
> Seamless integration
>   into your pages

There is a good article about it here: [Hand.js: a polyfill for supporting pointer events on every browser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/01/16/hand-js-a-polyfill-for-supporting-pointer-events-on-every-browser.aspx)